# C# - FindControl by ID and modify some properties

Tags: c#

I'm creating some checkbox's from codebehind (adding through Panel.Controls.Add()).
My question is: How can i modify the values?

I've already tried creating the control, use the method FindControl and them change some properties but with no sucess.

```
 CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
 c.FindControl("CheckBoxP");
 c.Checked = true;
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Do we talk ASP.Net? Winforms, etc. etc. Show us some more code, examples of usage :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (assuming you're using Windows Forms):

```
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        if (c.Name == "MyName" && c is CheckBox)
        {
            ((CheckBox)c).Checked = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this may be not works, cause the CheckBox is nested somewhere deeper in another container control (e.g. TableLayoutPanel, SplitContainer, etc.)

Comment: Yeah thats true, it assumes you know which control your target control is on.

Answer (score 1):

```
    CheckBox _C = (CheckBox)this.Controls.Find("checkBox1", true).FirstOrDefault();
    if (_C != null)
    {
        _C.Checked = true;
    }
```

replace the 'checkBox1' with the name of the desired control